# Sending Image file from Client(Android) to Server(ASP.NET)

Tags: android, .net

I need to send a file from client(Android) to Server(ASP.NET), for many days I have been looking for a piece of code,any help would be appreciated. I am advised to use HTTP.

Comment: Please remove the vote to close, I need the server side code(which is more necessary and important)too which is not in the link provided.

Comment: Are you new to ASP.NET? All you need to do is process HttpRequest and save. Try googling.

Comment: Yes I am really new to ASP.NET, any code snippet for the server side for the client request in the link you provided would be of great help. Googling didnot help me much

Comment: ASP.NEt i worked long back, and small googling returned this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1757/File-Upload-with-ASP-NET#get Hope it helps u.

Comment: Or else you might need to create Http Handlers in your ASP.NET project.